# android error adding to play store

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when uploading my app to the Google Play Store. What am I doing wrong?

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a certificate that is currently valid. Find out more about signing.  You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

Comment: Can you make it more clear that is the error message you're getting? I thought this was meant to be posted as an answer at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Google play will not allow you to upload packages with the name `com.example`. Rename your packages from `com.example.*` to `com.sonib.*` (for example)
2. Click the link in the error message to learn how to sign your app with a valid certificate. Follow the steps to get a certificate and sign your app. Note: You may need to purchase a secure certificate. This is required to upload public applications to the Google Play Store.

How to sign your app: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Here is one example of where to buy a certificate: there are many possible vendors, so feel free to shop around.

Where to buy a certificate: https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/code-signing/android

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided says **com.example** is restricted as APK package name, so the issue is clearly that you named your application this, which is invalid on Google Play.

Change your project name and you should be good to go.

I have not run into this issue on the Google Play Marketplace, but I would imagine you will also get the same error of you attempt to use the same package name as an application already published in the store.

As far as the certificate goes, I am assuming you are using Android Studio. Simply build a **Signed APK** from the build menu. This is how I create the APKs I publish on Google Play and I have never had an issue.